# Is it correct to say "under the war"

Tags: prepositions

this is my first question, so I hope I'm doing it right.

My students keep writing "under the war" and "under WW2". I would have intuitively written "**during** the war", but since I'm not a native speaker myself, I'm starting to doubt... Who is right?

Comment: You need (or should) provide a sample sentence, "under the war" is a fragment and as such it is really difficult (for me at least) to know if your students are using it correctly or appropriately. For example, you could say "blah, blah, blah, [under war conditions...."](https://www.google.com/search?ei=mXsqWpWaLYb7UpS7iWg&q=%22under+war+conditions%22&oq=%22under+war+conditions%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1l9j0i8i10i30k1.3925.13906.0.14182.2.2.0.0.0.0.158.305.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.305...33i22i29i30k1.0.9nWyXrDXpEs)

Comment: In the years before as well as ***under the Korean War*** logistics was described and used .......https://www.google.it/search?lr=lang_en&dcr=0&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1970%2Ccd_max%3A2008%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=S3sqWvfFH4vSkwWfob7ACw&q=%22under+the+korean+war%22&oq=%22under+the+korean+war%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...172631.173979.0.174274.7.7.0.0.0.0.227.958.1j5j1.7.0....0...1c..64.mobile-gws-serp..2.2.252...30i10k1.0.VP9GJbQWsYg

Comment: Using *under the war* in place of *during the war*  seems really weird and unusual.

Answer (score 3):

The term *under* in this context has the notion of *related to*, rather than *during the interval of*.

> **under** *preposition*
>   5.1 In a state of.
>   ‘For decades, he helped many of them to survive under difficult circumstances.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/under)

Here's an example:

- The World under the War
  [- Chapter 10, The War in the Air by Herbert George Wells](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=kUoUJ9LFLQgC&pg=PA211&dq=%22under%20the%20war%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKnN_Rq_rXAhVHi5QKHZxKDjQQ6AEIPjAE#v=onepage&q=%22under%20the%20war%22&f=false)

If the context was more along the lines of the following, it wouldn't be appropriate to replace *during* with *under*:

- During the war, both sides traditionally honored a general ceasefire during the holiday.
  [- Chapter 7, Chemical Warfare During the Vietnam War by D. Hank Ellison](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=enSrAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA88&dq=%22during%20the%20war%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1u8ebrvrXAhXCFpQKHUCeATg4HhDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=%22during%20the%20war%22&f=false)

The phrase *during the war* in that sentence relates simply to time. Ceasefires during holidays are not intrinsic to warfare.

However, there are contexts in which a case could be made to interpret the phrase either as simply a time reference or as a reference to the conditions of the war. Here's an example:

- There certainly hadn't been that many customers during the war, so Missouri was delighted to have some business, especially with a Confederate soldier.
  [- Page 50, Southern Memories During the War Between the States by Anne L. Terio](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=9e12sRWFkogC&pg=PA50&dq=%22during%20the%20war%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7osPyrPrXAhWJa7wKHS49B2s4ChDoAQhFMAU#v=onepage&q=%22during%20the%20war%22&f=false)

If you replaced *during* with *under*, the sense of the sentence would be that the *conditions* of war led to low patronage. As written, the sense is more strongly that of a time reference.

One might argue that the *ceasefire* example could be coerced to fit the phrase *under the war*, or counter that the *customers* example cannot be so coerced. In the final analysis, the intent of the author should be brought to bear by considering the broader context. The term *war* already brings up connotations of hardship etc, but *under* amplifies these connotations much more than *during*.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! It really helps! I don't think my students had such subtle differences in mind when using the preposition "under", though... But it's good to know when I am supposed to correct them - in some cases the "condition-rather-than-time"-reading will probably hold :)

Comment: @laura You're welcome; glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

OP needs to provide more context.

If the meaning is "during the period of time when WW2 was happening" then "during" is correct.

I cannot think of any correct use of "under" in this context and it sounds very much like students translating from their own language 1:1 which is a frequent problem with prepositions.

Comment: Thanks!
One example that I have in front of me right now is "this book gives you a really good picture of how kids lived under the war". Maybe in this case the reading of the type "under those condition" would make the use of "under" acceptable. I do believe that my students are translating 1:1 from their mother tongue (Norwegian "under" means both "under" and "during"...), but I want to be sure before I correct them! Any feedback on this example would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: In your example, "during" is also correct and "under" again wrong. You could say "Under the Hitler regime" or "Under the 3rd reich, life was very difficult" with the meaning "when X was in power/charge" but for time periods, it's always during.

Comment: Thank you, SonOfPingu! It's a subtle difference for a non-native speaker, but I think I understand. Your comment really helps :)